# C# DateTime The last 1 days of each month

Tags: c#, datetime

Yesterday. Here we subtract one day from the current day. We do this by adding -1 to the current day. This is necessary because no "Subtract Days" method is provided.
Note:
The example was run a few years ago. The output will naturally vary depending on the day you run it.
And:
DateTime.Today is always set to the machine's local time, which depends on the current system.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Before posting take a bit of your time to read the [help] and in particular [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public DateTime GetLastDayOfMonth(int year, int month)
{
    month += 1;
    if (month>12)
    {
        month = 1;
    }
    return new DateTime(year, month, 1).AddDays(-1);
}
```